# How can I read a WCF message from a file?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I'm developing a WCF client that accesses a third-party SOAP service, but I'm having trouble deserializing messages.

I have dumps of raw messages, but there isn't an obvious way to read them.

How can I read SOAP messages from a file using WCF?

Answer (score 1):

To read a message from a stream in WCF, you need a `MessageEncoder`.  For SOAP messages, you can get that through `TextMessageEncodingBindingElement`.

The following code worked for me:

```
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement binding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(
    MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
MessageEncoderFactory factory = binding.CreateMessageEncoderFactory();
MessageEncoder encoder = factory.CreateSessionEncoder();

TypedMessageConverter tmc = TypedMessageConverter.Create(
    typeof(GetDataResponse), "getDataResponse");

GetDataResponse response;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Response-20180918111722079.log",  FileMode.Open))
{   
    Message msg = encoder.ReadMessage(fs, 4096);
    response = tmc.FromMessage(msg);
}

// Use your response here.
```